# Python scipy Curve fit for quadratic function stopping early

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So my plotted line of best fit for a curve is cutting off at the second point and I for the life of me can't figure out why.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
accuracy = 250

def quadratic_function(E,a,b,c):    
    B = (a*(E**2.0)) + (b*E) + c
    return B

Implantation_E = np.array([5.0,10.0,15.0,20.0,25.0])

plt.figure()
plt.title("A plot showing how the Magnetic Field varies with Implantation Energy")
plt.ylabel("Magnetic Field Strength (T)")
plt.xlabel("Implantation Energy (J)")
plt.plot(Implantation_E,D_array[0],'bo')
parameters, var = curve_fit(quadratic_function,Implantation_E,D_array[0], absolute_sigma = True, p0 = (1.0,1.0,1.0))
newTime = np.linspace(0,10,accuracy)
newAsymmetry = quadratic_function(newTime, *parameters)
plt.plot(newTime, newAsymmetry) 
plt.show()
```

(Note D_array[0] : [ 0.00523265  0.00860683  0.0109838   0.01241191  0.01284149]
)

[image: Image of plotted graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original data range in their argument from 5 to 25. But your fit only goes to 10. Change the `newTime` definition to reach 25 and you are fine.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
%matplotlib inline

accuracy = 250

def quadratic_function(E,a,b,c):    
    B = (a*(E**2.0)) + (b*E) + c
    return B

dd= np.array([ 0.00523265, 0.00860683 ,0.0109838, 0.01241191 ,0.01284149])
Implantation_E = np.array([5.0,10.0,15.0,20.0,25.0])

plt.plot(Implantation_E,dd,'b-o',lw=15,ms=10,alpha=0.3)

parameters, var = curve_fit(quadratic_function,Implantation_E,dd,absolute_sigma = True, p0 = (1.0,1.0,1.0))
newTime = np.linspace(0,10,accuracy)
newAsymmetry = quadratic_function(newTime, *parameters)

plt.plot(newTime, newAsymmetry,'r.',ms=1) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
...
newTime = np.linspace(3,25,accuracy)
...
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks a lot, you wouldn't happen to know why when I add this too, it just causes it to join the dots when I add errors?

Comment: plt.errorbar(Implantation_E, D_array[0], xerr = 0.0, yerr = D_array[1])

Comment: D_array[1] = 1.66096809e-05   1.53262814e-05   1.62771310e-05   1.88651405e-05
   1.56005258e-05